# PathRemoveFileSpecA deprecated: What to use instead?

Tags: windows, winapi, path

Right now, I have:

- `GetModuleFileNameA` to get the executable that has loaded my DLL as a `char`string
- `MapAndLoad`, which *only* accepts `char`strings, to look at that executable's metadata

I want to remove the filename and just get the directory of the executable, so I can load a DLL that's specifically in the same directory. Yet, `PathCchRemoveFileSpec` doesn't take `char`strings. What do I do?

Comment: Use unicode everywhere, use PathCchRemoveFileSpec and convert unicode -> ansi for MapAndLoad.

Comment: Use a version of MapAndLoad that accepts Unicode file names. Although if you want to load a dll that you find in the filesystem I don't know why you'd use MapAndLoad.

Comment: `PathRemoveFileSpecA` "is deprecated" - and so what ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan my DLL is already loaded. I want to grab the `TimeDateStamp` from the EXE that loaded my DLL. Also, there is no `MapAndLoadW`.

Comment: Well, you don't need MapAndLoad for that.